# How to swap x ticks with date strings in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am following a bar chart tutorial on matplotlib via:

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849513265/1/ch01lvl1sec16/plotting-multiple-bar-charts

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[5., 25., 50., 20.],
  [4., 23., 51., 17.],
  [6., 22., 52., 19.]]

color_list = ['b', 'g', 'r']
gap = .8 / len(data)
for i, row in enumerate(data):
  X = np.arange(len(row))
  plt.bar(X + i * gap, row,
    width = gap,
    color = color_list[i % len(color_list)])

plt.show()
```

Here is the code I am using which is also the code from the link. I create the graph depicted in the link but am having trouble modifying the x axis values / xticks and replacing it with dates

```
plt.xticks(['11-2019', '12-2019', '01-2020'])
```

I am subject to the error:

> in convert_units
>       f'units: {x!r}') from e matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['11-2019', '12-2019', '01-2020']

Does anyone know how to swap the x axis values to the dates above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xticks` of matplotlib need the position and the labels. From the [documentary](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html):

```
xticks(ticks, [labels], **kwargs)  # Set locations and labels
```

If you want to use your custom ticks, add a position. You can just use `np.arange` to create a series of values, which are your positions. Also i added another tick (literally) but it is not mandatory. If you just use three ticks, just three appear.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(4),['11-2019', '12-2019', '01-2020', 'another tick'])
```

Output:

[image: Figure]

Comment: Thanks. This works. However my legend is not appearing:

Comment: plt.legend((data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]), ('17-24', '25-34','35-49','50-100'), loc='upper left')

Comment: @YieldedTemparz not sure what you want to create with this syntax. But before i give you a working sample: This is another question, in general you should open a new question on Stackoverflow. Also this one would be not appropriate to create, since this is a very easy task which can be done by using google or the [documentary](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html). For your legend: You can create a legend by using `legend(("17-24', '25-34','35-49'), loc="upper left")`. This creates a legend for each list you used to create the plot which is data [1].